# Summation Representation for the Column of a Matrix Product

Tags: matrices, proof-verification

Let A be an $m \times m$ matrix and B be a $m \times n$ matrix. I know that the matrix product AB=C can be represented as such

$(AB)_{ij}=\sum^m_{k=1} A_{ik}B_{kj}=C_{ij}$

For a different proof I am working on, I want a summation form that picks out the $j$th column of C. If I use the above expression, would I be able to write the $j$th column $C_j$ such that

$(AB)_j=C_j=\sum_{k=1}^mA_kB_{kj}$

Since this encompasses each row $i$?

If this is the case, in my proof can I just make that jump or are there any steps in between I might have to show?

If this is not the case, can anyone point me to the expression of how to show the column in that form?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The entire $C$ matrix is
$$
C=\begin{pmatrix}
(AB)_{11}& (AB)_{12} & \cdots& (AB)_{1n}\\
(AB)_{21}& (AB)_{22} & \cdots& (AB)_{2n}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
(AB)_{m1}& (AB)_{m2} & \cdots &(AB)_{mn}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
so the $j$th column of $C$ must be
$$
C_{\cdot j}=\begin{pmatrix}
(AB)_{1j}\\
(AB)_{2j}\\
\vdots\\
(AB)_{mj}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\begin{pmatrix}
\sum_{k=1}^m A_{1k}B_{kj}\\
\sum_{k=1}^m A_{2k}B_{kj}\\
\vdots\\
\sum_{k=1}^m A_{mk}B_{kj}
\end{pmatrix}
=\sum_{k=1}^m
\begin{pmatrix}
 A_{1k}B_{kj}\\
 A_{2k}B_{kj}\\
\vdots\\
 A_{mk}B_{kj}
\end{pmatrix}
=\sum_{k=1}^m
\begin{pmatrix}
 A_{1k}\\
 A_{2k}\\
\vdots\\
 A_{mk}
\end{pmatrix}B_{kj}
=\sum_{k=1}^mA_{\cdot k}B_{kj}
$$
which is what you conjectured. Note that I added some dots in place of the row indexes for clarity only ($A_k$ is ambiguous - it is not obvious if it refers to the $k$th row or column).